# Embedded Tomcat enable SSL

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

I'm trying to setup SSL for embedded Tomcat. Both connectors starts but I only get response on http. On https I get in chrome a "No data received message" when I try `http://localhost:9000/`
The port is open:
I've tried telnet
  `telnet localhost 9000` 
and I have a connection.
I've also tried 
  `openssl s_client -connect localhost:9000`
and GET / method
and my servlet prints me the expected result in console. I do not understand why I get this error in browsers(chrome and Firefox)
My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and I've tried with both Java 7 and Java 8 having the same result. Tomcat version is 8.0.23 from Maven repo
The code is:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    Service service = tomcat.getService();
    service.addConnector(getSslConnector());


    File base = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    Context rootCtx = tomcat.addContext("/", base.getAbsolutePath());
    Tomcat.addServlet(rootCtx, "emptyServlet", new EmptyServlet());
    rootCtx.addServletMapping("/*", "emptyServlet");
    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();

}

private static Connector getSslConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector();
    connector.setPort(9000);
    connector.setSecure(true);
    connector.setScheme("https");
    connector.setAttribute("keyAlias", "tomcat");
    connector.setAttribute("keystorePass", "password");
    connector.setAttribute("keystoreType", "JKS");
    connector.setAttribute("keystoreFile",
            "keystore.jks");
    connector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "false");
    connector.setAttribute("protocol", "HTTP/1.1");
    connector.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "TLS");
    connector.setAttribute("maxThreads", "200");
    connector.setAttribute("protocol", "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol");
    connector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", true);
    return connector;
 }
}
```

The keystore you can find it on [github](https://github.com/danjee/tomcatembedded/tree/master/tomcat.8080)

I've already tried different keystores but with the same result. Also the keystore looks good: `keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks` seems to be as expected.
  Thanks in advance

Comment: IIUC: You have some kind of Java program. So, please add more information, the code in question and details about the failure/expected result.

Comment: The code is on github. A link is provided in the description. I can paste it here also if it's a must. I expect HTTPS will be enabled on embedded Tomcat just like on regular Tomcat, but browsers fails in rendering the output.

Comment: You should post some information here. IOW: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: your code solved my issue. much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be my fault. The service was up and running but I kept on trying on http://localhost:9000 not https://locahost:9000 in my browser